# What happens when interrupt on thread which does not waiting for a lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have query that if I invoked interrupt on a thread A which is not in Waiting Status. I know that interrupt() will cause thread premature release from waiting with an Interrupted Exception. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. You can't magically *cause* a thread to throw an `InterruptedException` by calling `interrupt` on it. If the thread is not "cooperative" it can ignore any interrupts. This for instance will not even compile: `try { int x = Integer.parseInt("0"); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the JavaDoc of [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) you should see:

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), ....
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation ....
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector ....
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this **thread's interrupt status will be set**.

So - essentially, the thread's *interrupt status will be set*, and that's it!